# Using git interactive rebase from within a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, git

I'd like to create a bash script to automate a sequence of Git actions I do very frequently to apply my unstaged changes to an earlier commit, as in:

- Stash changes;
- Enter interactive rebase;
- Edit the commit in question;
- Apply the stash to it;
- Finalize the rebase.

Problem is, some of these actions open up Vim and I'm not sure how to edit/write to file using a bash script. I don't want to do this manually.

Is there a way to automate editing in Vim using bash? Is there a better way to do this that covers cases where Vim isn't the default editor?

Comment: I understand that the question is about automating the vim part of your workflow, but I think you'll get better responses on solving this problem over at StackOverflow. That said, I did find a related link on this problem: https://blog.filippo.io/git-fixup-amending-an-older-commit/

Comment: @Haxiel thanks, that's a MUCH simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

I guess VIM always opens up when git expects you to type in a descriptive message.
You can circumvent this by providing the message to the relevant git command via the "-m" option.

e.g. see: git stash --help

```
...
git stash store [-m|--message <message>] [-q|--quiet] <commit>
...
```

additional info after clarification in comments:

There is a non-interactive (the original ex) mode in VIM: "vim -e", running the command "ex" from bash should also work. But you still would need to pipe the vim commands into it. Abusing the $EDITOR env just before your git rebase call should do it, e.g. (the -s is for silent mode):

```
export EDITOR="cat commands.vim | vim -es"
```

But when you already abuse the $EDITOR env you could also just write another bash script that does the file modifications and use that as editor:

```
export EDITOR="/path/to/your/script/"
```

Anyway, don't forget to reset your $EDITOR after that.

Comment: Nope, as soon as you enter interactive rebase you're given a text file with a legend to control what you want to do to the commits. I also avoid using `-m` cause it only gives me control over one line.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are trying to achive. Since you are starting a interactive rebase, you have to choose somehow which commits to pick, etc. So what exactly do you want to automate?

Comment: I want to automate it using the commit hash so I already know which one I want to edit... That's what I want to automate. But for that, I need to edit/write the interactive rebase menu file in Vim.
Which is why I want to know if there's a way to control Vim using a bash script.

Comment: please check my addon to the original answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit. A friend gave me a similar solution and I do think this is the way to go.